# How to place Icons Inside a Data Gird (Material UI)? How describe it in Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

This is my Data Gird

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { DataGrid, GridColDef } from '@material-ui/data-grid'
import { ProductService } from '../services/ProductServices'

const columns: GridColDef[] = [
  { field: 'id', headerName: 'Id', type: 'number', width: 70 },
  { field: 'name', headerName: 'Nome', width: 200 },
  { field: 'description', headerName: 'Descrição', width: 400 },
  { field: 'price', headerName: 'Preço', type: 'number', width: 130 },
  { field: 'quantity', headerName: 'Quantidade', type: 'number', width: 130 },
  { field: 'situation', headerName: 'situação', type: 'number', width: 130 }
]

some code here geting the rows...

export const ProductBox: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%', marginTop: 75 }}>
      <DataGrid rows={rows} columns={columns} pageSize={5} checkboxSelection />
    </div>
  )
}
```

And this is my row Interface:

```
interface IProduct {
  id: number
  name: string
  price: number
  description: string
  quantity: number
  situation: string
}
```

How to place a field with icon? And how to say that my icon is an icon for typescript?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem! Found the answer here:

https://material-ui.com/pt/components/data-grid/columns/

Comment: check [this](https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/columns/#render-header) too, it might help